# Creating personal wiki reading my own file

Tags: python, key-value, wiki, summary

I'm trying to create a personal wiki that instead of searching info from a wikipedia API with the summary function, it search my own info that is related to a key in a file (key-value) that I create. What should I do to make it work?

```
def _(text):
    try:
        textarea.delete('1.0', END)
        text = text.lower()
        value = wikipedia.summary(text, sentences=15)
        value = value + '\n\n'
        for word in value:
            textarea.insert(END, word)
    except wikipedia.DisambiguationError as e:
            s = random.choice(e.options)
            s = s.lower()
            p = wikipedia.summary(s)
            p = p + '\n\n'
            for word in p:
                textarea.insert(END, word)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would argue that you probably shouldn't. Instead identify a suitable Wiki engine/product to host your '_personal wiki_'. One that meets your needs. Why build something that is surely inferior when you can just identify, download, and use something '_tried and true_' . My biggest requirement is support for a well-defined markdown standard, e.g. CommonMark, GitHub Flavored Markdown (GFM) or the like. That gives me the freedom to move it if I end up not liking my chosen engine.

Comment: Hi Scott! You're right but I'm learning python and I wanted to try and create one also as an excuse to learn and improve my skills.

Comment: Understood @Mttf. I'm a Python newbie myself so hopefully others can help. Best of luck.